# Getting info out of each loop for use in the next without terminating the loop (Python)

Tags: python

I'm sorry if this is asked elsewhere, but what searching I did didn't bring up the info I needed and I didn't quite know what other keywords to use to search further.  Please understand that I'm quite new to programming.

OK, now onto business.  I have two for loops set up.  The first cycles through a list and concatenates it with a couple of other strings inputted through variables.  The second takes the string made in the first loop and concatenates data from a different loop onto it.  However, when I execute the function, the second loop only uses the last result from the previous loop rather than attaching the data to all the strings formed from the first loop.  Here's an example:

```
j=0
k=0
for j in xrange(0, 2):
        for k in xrange(0, 2):
                first=(a + sign[k] + b)
                k = k+1
        second=(first + sign[j] + c)
        print(second)
        j = j+1
```

where a, b, c, and sign[] are variables.

The output I want is:

```
a + sign[0] + b + sign[0] + c
a + sign[1] + b + sign[0] + c
a + sign[0] + b + sign[1] + c
a + sign[1] + b + sign[1] + c
```

The output I get is:

```
a + sign[1] + b + sign[0] + c
a + sign[1] + b + sign[1] + c
```

(Well, I'm going to be using more values, but that's the general gist of it)

Is there any way I can get the data out of the first loop without stopping it for use in the second loop to make a list such as this, i.e. get the code to use sign[0] in the first instance and not just sign[1]?  Also, I would just like to reiterate that I'm quite new to coding, so please bear that in mind when responding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to print the elements in the inner loop, this way you print for each different value of `j` and `k`.

Also note, you don't need to manually increase `j` and `k` - it is taken care of by itself, since it is the loop variable of your for-each loop.

You could also change the size of the list, which is currently hardcoded to be 2 - to be more flexible using the `len()` function:

```
>>> for j in xrange(0,len(sign)):
...   for k in xrange(0,len(sign)):
...     first = a + sign[k] + b
...     second = first + sign[j] + c
...     print(second)
...
```

Output (I set `a='a',b='b',c='c',sign=['0','1']`)

```
a0b0c
a1b0c
a0b1c
a1b1c
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!  Thank you so much! I didn't realise you could call the variable from the outer loop in the inner loop.  Thanks again!  This is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
for first, second in itertools.product(sign[:2], sign[:2]):
    print a + first + b + second + c
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have an error in your code that you implement `k` one time too much. The `for` loop makes sure that `k` increments, but you have also `k = k + 1` in there, so during each iteration you're incrementing by 2:

```
for k in xrange(0, 2):
    first = ....
    k = k + 1              # should this be here?
```

That way the `for` loop will run just once, with one `k` value of zero.